# How to iterate through a nested list or compound list to perform calculations for each list within the list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, iteration, nested-lists

I am learning Python, and I am trying to iterate through a compound list that is created when the user types in a chemical formula. For example if the chemical formula is H2O for a molecule of water the compound list will be:

```
list = [
       ['H', 2],
       ['O', 1]
]
```

If the chemical formula is C6H12O6 for the compound Glucose the compound list will be:

```
list = [
       ['C', 6],
       ['H', 12],
       ['O', 6]
]
```

I want to iterate through the entire compound list and calculate the mass percentage for each element in the list and display them to the user no matter how many elements the user types in. The problem that I am running into with my code is that when I try to compute the mass percentage for each element within the compound list, it pulls only the last element in the list and performs the calculations for only that element. So when I enter in C6H12O6 for Glucose it will perform the calculations only for O or Oxygen, but I also want to do the others for Carbon and Hydrogen. My function compute mass percentage performs the calculations, but I am unsure if it will work for what I am trying to accomplish. I need to do this all within functions and the other functions have to stay the way that they are. I also can't change the really long dictionary that contains all of the elements with their correlated atomic mass in the function make periodic table. The only function that I can really make changes to is my compute mass percentage function and how it is called in the main() function.

Here is how I am calculating the mass percentage of an element from a chemical formula. In this example I am getting the mass percentage of Carbon in glucose.

Sum the number of atoms of each element in the formula for glucose:

```
6 carbon atoms
12 hydrogen atoms
6 oxygen atoms
```

Find the atomic mass of each element:
Symbol  Name       Atomic Mass

```
C       Carbon     12.0107
H       Hydrogen   1.00794
O       Oxygen     15.9994
```

Multiply the number of atoms by their atomic mass:

```
6   ×   12.0107 =   72.0642
12  ×   1.00794 =   12.09528
6   ×   15.9994 =   95.9964
```

Add the results of the multiplications to get the molar mass of glucose:

```
72.0642 + 12.09528 + 95.9964 = 180.15588 grams/mole
```

Now we are going to get the **mass percentage** of Carbon in glucose instead of the number of moles in a sample of glucose:

```
72.0642 / 180.15588 = 0.40001026 or 40%
```

So, Carbon makes up 40% of the mass that is in glucose.

Here is my code for my program. I only know how to code in Python by the way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
ELEMENT_SYMBOL = 0
ATOMS = 1


def main():

    # Get a chemical formula for a molecule from the user.

    chemical_formula = input("Enter the molecular formula of the sample: ").title()
    
    # Get a mass in grams from the user.

    mass = float(input("Enter the mass in grams of the sample: "))



    # Call the make_periodic_table function and
    # store the periodic table in a variable.

    dictionary = make_periodic_table()


    # Call the parse_formula function to convert the
    # chemical formula given by the user to a compound
    # list that stores element symbols and the quantity
    # of atoms of each element in the molecule.

    element_group = parse_formula(chemical_formula, dictionary)
    

    # Call the compute_molar_mass function to compute the
    # molar mass of the molecule from the compound list.

    molar_mass = compute_molar_mass(element_group, dictionary)


    # Call the compute_mass_percentage function to compute the
    # mass percentage of the molecule from the compound list.

    mass_percent = compute_mass_percentage(element_group, dictionary)


    # Compute the number of moles of the sample.

    moles = mass / molar_mass

    # Print the molar mass.

    print(f"{molar_mass:.5f} grams/mole")

    # Print the number of moles.

    print(f"{moles:.5f} moles")

    print(parse_formula(chemical_formula, dictionary))

    print(f"{mass_percent}")
    
    

    
    
def make_periodic_table():
    
    table = {
            "Ac":   ["Actinium",        227],
            "Ag":   ["Silver",          107.8682],
            "Al":   ["Aluminum",        26.9815386],
            "Am":   ["Americium",       243],
            "Ar":   ["Argon",           39.948],
            "As":   ["Arsenic",         74.9216],
            "At":   ["Astatine",        210],
            "Au":   ["Gold",            196.966569],
            "B":    ["Boron",           10.811],
            "Ba":   ["Barium",          137.327],
            "Be":   ["Beryllium",       9.012182],
            "Bh":   ["Bohrium",         272],
            "Bi":   ["Bismuth",         208.9804],
            "Bk":   ["Berkelium",       247],
            "Br":   ["Bromine",         79.904],
            "C":    ["Carbon",          12.0107],
            "Ca":   ["Calcium",         40.078],
            "Cd":   ["Cadmium",         112.411],
            "Ce":   ["Cerium",          140.116],
            "Cf":   ["Californium",     251],
            "Cl":   ["Chlorine",        35.453],
            "Cm":   ["Curium",          247],
            "Cn":   ["Copernicium",     285],
            "Co":   ["Cobalt",          58.933195],
            "Cr":   ["Chromium",        51.9961],
            "Cs":   ["Cesium",          132.9054519],
            "Cu":   ["Copper",          63.546],
            "Db":   ["Dubnium",         268],
            "Ds":   ["Darmstadtium",    281],
            "Dy":   ["Dysprosium",      162.5],
            "Er":   ["Erbium",          167.2590],
            "Es":   ["Einsteinium",     252],
            "Eu":   ["Europium",        151.964],
            "F":    ["Fluorine",        18.9984032],
            "Fe":   ["Iron",            55.845],
            "Fl":   ["Flerovium",       289],
            "Fm":   ["Fermium",         257],
            "Fr":   ["Francium",        223],
            "Ga":   ["Gallium",         69.723],
            "Gd":   ["Gadolinium",      157.25],
            "Ge":   ["Germanium",       72.64],
            "H":    ["Hydrogen",        1.00794],
            "He":   ["Helium",          4.002602],
            "Hf":   ["Hafnium",         178.49],
            "Hg":   ["Mercury",         200.59],
            "Ho":   ["Holmium",         164.93032],
            "Hs":   ["Hassium",         270],
            "I":    ["Iodine",          126.90447],
            "In":   ["Indium",          114.818],
            "Ir":   ["Iridium",         192.217],
            "K":    ["Potassium",       39.0983],
            "Kr":   ["Krypton",         83.798],
            "La":   ["Lanthanum",       138.90547],
            "Li":   ["Lithium",         6.941],
            "Lr":   ["Lawrencium",      262],
            "Lu":   ["Lutetium",        174.9668],
            "Lv":   ["Livermorium",     293],
            "Mc":   ["Moscovium",       288],
            "Md":   ["Mendelevium",     258],
            "Mg":   ["Magnesium",       24.305],
            "Mn":   ["Manganese",       54.938045],
            "Mo":   ["Molybdenum",      95.96],
            "Mt":   ["Meitnerium",      276],
            "N":    ["Nitrogen",        14.0067],
            "Na":   ["Sodium",          22.98976928],
            "Nb":   ["Niobium",         92.90638],
            "Nd":   ["Neodymium",       144.242],
            "Ne":   ["Neon",            20.1797],
            "Nh":   ["Nihonium",        284],
            "Ni":   ["Nickel",          58.6934],
            "No":   ["Nobelium",        259],
            "Np":   ["Neptunium",       237],
            "O":    ["Oxygen",          15.9994],
            "Og":   ["Oganesson",       294],
            "Os":   ["Osmium",          190.23],
            "P":    ["Phosphorus",      30.973762],
            "Pa":   ["Protactinium",    231.03588],
            "Pb":   ["Lead",            207.2],
            "Pd":   ["Palladium",       106.42],
            "Pm":   ["Promethium",      145],
            "Po":   ["Polonium",        209],
            "Pr":   ["Praseodymium",    140.90765],
            "Pt":   ["Platinum",        195.084],
            "Pu":   ["Plutonium",       244],
            "Ra":   ["Radium",          226],
            "Rb":   ["Rubidium",        85.4678],
            "Re":   ["Rhenium",         186.207],
            "Rf":   ["Rutherfordium",   267],
            "Rg":   ["Roentgenium",     280],
            "Rh":   ["Rhodium",         102.9055],
            "Rn":   ["Radon",           222],
            "Ru":   ["Ruthenium",       101.07],
            "S":    ["Sulfur",          32.065],
            "Sb":   ["Antimony",        121.76],
            "Sc":   ["Scandium",        44.955912],
            "Se":   ["Selenium",        78.96],
            "Sg":   ["Seaborgium",      271],
            "Si":   ["Silicon",         28.0855],
            "Sm":   ["Samarium",        150.36],
            "Sn":   ["Tin",             118.71],
            "Sr":   ["Strontium",       87.62],
            "Ta":   ["Tantalum",        180.94788],
            "Tb":   ["Terbium",         158.92535],
            "Tc":   ["Technetium",      98],
            "Te":   ["Tellurium",       127.6],
            "Th":   ["Thorium",         232.03806],
            "Ti":   ["Titanium",        47.867],
            "Tl":   ["Thallium",        204.3833],
            "Tm":   ["Thulium",         168.93421],
            "Ts":   ["Tennessine",      294],
            "U":    ["Uranium",         238.02891],
            "V":    ["Vanadium",        50.9415],
            "W":    ["Tungsten",        183.84],
            "Xe":   ["Xenon",           131.293],
            "Y":    ["Yttrium",         88.90585],
            "Yb":   ["Ytterbium",       173.054],
            "Zn":   ["Zinc",            65.38],
            "Zr":   ["Zirconium",       91.224]
    }

    return table


class FormulaError(ValueError):
    """FormulaError is the type of error that
    parse_formula will raise if a formula is invalid.
    """
    pass


def parse_formula(formula, periodic_table_dict):
    """Convert a chemical formula for a molecule into a compound list
    that stores the quantity of atoms of each element in the molecule.
    For example, this function will convert "H2O" to [["H", 2], ["O", 1]]
    and "PO4H2(CH2)12CH3" to [["P", 1], ["O", 4], ["H", 29], ["C", 13]]
    """
    def parse_quant(formula, index):
        quant = 1
        if index < len(formula) and formula[index].isdecimal():
            start = index
            index += 1
            while index < len(formula) and formula[index].isdecimal():
                index += 1
            quant = int(formula[start:index])
        return quant, index

    def get_quant(elems, symbol):
        return 0 if symbol not in elems else elems[symbol]

    def parse_r(formula, index, level):
        start_index = index
        start_level = level
        elem_dict = {}
        while index < len(formula):
            ch = formula[index]
            if ch == "(":
                group_dict, index = parse_r(formula, index+1, level+1)
                quant, index = parse_quant(formula, index)
                for symbol in group_dict:
                    prev = get_quant(elem_dict, symbol)
                    elem_dict[symbol] = prev + group_dict[symbol] * quant
            elif ch.isalpha():
                symbol = formula[index:index+2]
                if symbol in periodic_table_dict:
                    index += 2
                else:
                    symbol = formula[index:index+1]
                    if symbol in periodic_table_dict:
                        index += 1
                    else:
                        raise FormulaError(
                            "invalid formula, unknown element symbol:",
                            formula, index)
                quant, index = parse_quant(formula, index)
                prev = get_quant(elem_dict, symbol)
                elem_dict[symbol] = prev + quant
            elif ch == ")":
                if level == 0:
                    raise FormulaError(
                        "invalid formula, unmatched close parenthesis:",
                        formula, index)
                level -= 1
                index += 1
                break
            else:
                if ch.isdecimal():
                    # Decimal digit not preceded by an
                    # element symbol or close parenthesis
                    message = "invalid formula:"
                else:
                    # Illegal character: [^()0-9a-zA-Z]
                    message = "invalid formula, illegal character:"
                raise FormulaError(message, formula, index)
        if level > 0 and level >= start_level:
            raise FormulaError(
                "invalid formula, unmatched open parenthesis:",
                formula, start_index - 1)
        return elem_dict, index

    # Return the compound list of element symbols and
    # quantities. Each element in the compound list
    # will be a list in this form: ["symbol", quantity]
    elem_dict, _ = parse_r(formula, 0, 0)
    return list(elem_dict.items())


# These are the indexes of the
# elements in the periodic table.
NAME_INDEX = 0
ATOMIC_MASS_INDEX = 1


def compute_molar_mass(symbol_quantity_list, periodic_table_dict):
    """Compute and return the total molar mass of all the
    elements listed in symbol_quantity_list. Each element in
    symbol_quantity_list is a list in the form: ["symbol", quantity].

    As an example, if symbol_quantity_list is [["H", 2], ["O", 1]],
    this function will calculate and return
    atomic_mass("H") * 2 + atomic_mass("O") * 1
    1.00794 * 2 + 15.9994 * 1
    18.01528
    """


    total_mass = 0.0
    
    for element in symbol_quantity_list:
        symbol = element[ELEMENT_SYMBOL]
        quantity = element[ATOMS]
        atomic_mass = periodic_table_dict[symbol][ATOMIC_MASS_INDEX]
        total_mass += atomic_mass * quantity
    
    return total_mass
        
    # For each element in the symbol_quantity_list:
    #   Split the element into symbol and quantity.
    #   Get the atomic mass for the symbol.
    #   Multiply the atomic mass by the quantity.
    #   Add the product into the total mass.

def compute_mass_percentage(symbol_quantity_list, periodic_table_dict):

    total_mass = 0.0
    mass_percent = 0.0
    
    for element in symbol_quantity_list:
        symbol = element[ELEMENT_SYMBOL]
        quantity = element[ATOMS]
        atomic_mass = periodic_table_dict[symbol][ATOMIC_MASS_INDEX]
        element_mass = quantity * atomic_mass
        total_mass += atomic_mass * quantity
        mass_percent = element_mass / total_mass
    
    return mass_percent


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

> The problem that I am running into with my code is that when I try to compute the mass percentage for each element within the compound list, it pulls only the last element in the list and performs the calculations for only that element.

You are mistaken - this isn't the problem. It performs the calculations for each element in the list just as it should. You only failed to store the result, so in each subsequent loop cycle the previous result is overwritten and finally only the last one is returned. To correct that and account for the fact that `total_mass` is not correct before the last computation is done, you can change

```
    mass_percent = 0.0
    …
        mass_percent = element_mass / total_mass
    
    return mass_percent
```

to

```
    masses = []
    …
        masses += [element_mass]
    return [element_mass / total_mass for element_mass in masses]
```